# RuntimeError:Mixing different tf.distribute.Strategy objects

Tags: google-colaboratory, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

Hello！I have encountered some problems when compiling the model using TPU.Some part of codes as follows:

```
resolver = tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TF_MASTER)

tf.contrib.distribute.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)

strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)

with strategy.scope():

  model = create_model()

  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics='accuracy'])
```

And I got RuntimeError:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhB2n.png)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by various chaos trying.You can restart your program or comment the code:

```
resolver = tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver
tf.contrib.distribute.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)

with strategy.scope():
  model = create_model()
  model.compile()
```

to avoid the problem

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. It seems the version of TensorFlow as default is 1.x. I change my code into: (comment 3 lines and add other lines)

```
try:
  # %tensorflow_version only exists in Colab.
  %tensorflow_version 2.x
except Exception:
  pass

# resolver = tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver('grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
# tf.contrib.distribute.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
# strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)
```

It solved.

Comment: @double-beep I finally found the key and improved my answer. Thanks.